# How to set the upper limit to make reading more flexible when reading area files by line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]This is my part of the code, you can see that I am reading and parsing the code line by line. I set 160 as the upper limit because my file has 160 lines. My code is completely runnable. But I raised a question, what should I do if I need to read more than 160 lines in the file? Therefore, I changed 160 to a larger number in the current file, and an error occurred during operation.
All in all, my question is, how should I set the range so that my code can read code of any length.

```
const fs=require("fs");
var filePath=process.argv[2];
const svg = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString();
var res = svg.split("\n");
let last="";
let start="X0 Y0";
var gcode = "";
var text = getpath(5);
gcode = "G0 X0 Y0 F1000\nM4 S1000\nM5"+gcode+"\nG0 X0 Y0 F200\n(things in brackets are comments)"

function getpath(x){
    var line =res[x];
    var parseLine= path2gcode(line);
    gcode=gcode+"\n"+parseLine.join('\n');
    //console.log(gcode);
    if(x>=5 && x<160){
        var tLine=x+1;
        getpath(tLine);
    }
    else{
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `x<res.length`?

Comment: length refers to the length of the string, but x here refers to the number of lines in the string. The picture can show the res.

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot instead of text block data

Comment: `res` is an array of strings. So res.length should be equal to 160 in case of your initial file

Comment: So you mean, the limit of x<160 can work with any similar files? Although other files are longer?

Comment: I mean `x<res.length` should work

Comment: An error was reported as   const result = source.replace(/M/g, ";M").replace(/L/g, ";L").replace(/z/g, ";z").split(';').slice(1);
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at processPathLettersIntoArray (/Users/chenyujie/Desktop/gcode2/solarSystem.js:52:27)
    at path2gcode (/Users/chenyujie/Desktop/gcode2/solarSystem.js:57:14)
    at getpath (/Users/chenyujie/Desktop/gcode2/solarSystem.js:14:20)

Comment: What error was reported?

Comment: When you do `var res = svg.split("\n");` then `res` is an array where `res.length` is the number of actual lines you have, doesn't matter if it's 160 or 10,000 so you don't have to hard-code `x<160` you can just `x<res.length` like Anatoly is saying. But never mind that, you can process all the lines by using `res.forEach( someProcessFunction )` without bothering to keep track of which line number you're on. And then you'd be iteratively processing lines in a loop, where now you are _recursively_ calling "getpath" -- which I can't see a reason to do.